# Always show asker on the front page

Tags: feature-request

The front page/"interesting" view currently shows the time and username for the last modification of a question; other views show the asker's username and the time at which the question was asked. The asker username/rep is much more interesting than the last-modifying username/rep for me, **since I am using the front page to find questions to answer which have been tagged with one of my favorited tags. I am not generally doing moderation.**

<s>My preference is to replace the last-modified information with asker information, but an alternative would be to show both asker and last-modifier information as appropriate.</s>

**update**

There seems to be a use-case for using the last-modified for moderation. Since this is the case, perhaps we can **add** the asker's info to the front page **in addition** to the last-modified information?

Or is there some reason to **not** add the asker's information on the front page?

Comment: removing the modification / answer information is a bad idea. Generally showing the askers information too, maybe.

Comment: If other people find the modification information useful, then adding the asker's info in addition works as well. I have personally never used the modification info for anything.

Comment: The [original reason for doing this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145039/179419) was to help people understand _why_ a question is on the front page. Why is this reason now not relevant? Why do _you_ think that the asker is more relevant? Something being "much more interesting" to one person is not a compelling reason to change, what would you use the askers username for? Why is it interesting?

Comment: I realize that this is contentious on SO, but I basically don't want to waste time looking at 100s of low quality questions. Rep is the only data we have to go on, so I want to be able to see the asker's rep rather than the rep of the person who cleaned up their poorly-formatted question. The question is (for me) interesting because it matches my favorited tags, not because somebody edited it.

Answer (score 2):

> The asker username/rep is much more interesting than the last-modifying username/rep.

Why?

To me the modification is more interesting, especially when it's an old question. Usually when "answered|modified by user123456789 (1 rep)" is stated on an old question in the question list or on the frontpage, it's spam, low-quality or vandalism and I need to edit, rollback or flag the modification.

You would miss that trigger when it'd still display the original asker's name.

Also, you can click the word "answered|modified" and go directly to the answer or modification, which I frequently use.

Comment: Now having the askers info *in addition* may be useful. Maybe.

Comment: Your wanting to keep the site clean is of course commendable, however I disagree completely with your answer here - the info snippet is for info on the question and answer, not as a method for moderating. If you want to perform moderation tasks we have the review queues. We don't need (or want) info all over the place making us aware of potential issues. This should be for a preview, to know what may be in the question - a high rep answerer for example means I might get a really good answer I was looking for. It comes under "interesting" tab, not "moderating/review queue" tab.

Comment: @James I'm not interested in nor using the review queues. I find reviewing Q&As in its current form very boring. I usually F5 the frontpage, and then I want to see _why that Q&A is on the frontpage_, which that "asked|answered|modified by" fulfills exactly. OP says: _"asker info is much more interesting"_, but doesn't tell why he thinks so - I _do_ explain why I find answerer information interesting.

Comment: But your not using the review queues doesn't mean we should put info showing *potential problems* in place of what should be just useful info about content. I don't think anyone particularly finds reviewing interesting. I find it laborious and boring, but I don't do it for excitement or pleasure, I do it to help the site.

Comment: @James see the edits to my comment and answer I made in the meantime. I still haven't heard a compelling reason to change it to only show asker info. I now have two cases for showing answerer info.

Comment: @CodeCaster Explained and request modified.

Comment: "I now have two cases for showing answerer info" - answerer info? Your answer seems like you are saying you prefer "modification" because you can use it to deem if the question or answer needs moderating - "t's spam, low-quality or vandalism and I need to edit, rollback or flag the modification"

Comment: @James that's right.

Comment: So, OP thinks option 1 is better and you think option 2 is better so it must be option 2. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it could show the username of the editor *as well as the one of the asker*, like this:

[image]

...Or maybe a configurable option somewhere.

Comment: That would indeed make much more sense IMO than to display *only* the editor/answerer and indeed, a configurable option would be the best fit. Really don't know why this simple **suggestion** is getting downvoted. I know it's an old topic but I'd really like to see that implemented.