# Get edits to old questions / answers off the front page, please

Tags: feature-request

I've been thinking why the Stack Overflow front page is so bad - in particular, the Interesting tab, which is what I see by default. And it occurs to me that one problem is that merely editing a question or answer causes this question to be promoted onto the front page.

Now, don't get me wrong. This is reasonable for *recent* questions, and in fact editing is used a way of "bumping" a question or answer, to bring it to people's notice. And I think that's a perfectly legitimate way to game the system.

But there seem to be people who spend their time roaming the archives and editing very old questions and answers, for no earthly reason that I can see (except perhaps that it gains them some sort of rep points or badges, I don't know and I don't care). And when they are at work, their edits dominate the Interesting tab, driving other stuff off. The fact is, however, that this kind of thing is *not interesting* and should *not* occupy this real estate on the front page.

Thus, I suggest, as a feature, that edits to questions or answers older than, say, one week should not appear on the Interesting tab.

**OR:**

If (as it appears) there are good reasons why that request can't be granted, then I suggest as an alternative feature that the Interesting tab should *list the "asked" date* for every question - thus allowing me to distinguish at a glance old questions from new ones.

Comment: What if a user decides to vandalize lots of his old posts? Those edits should be rolled back, but if they are not shown on the front page, it's less likely somebody will notice them.

Comment: This would depend on the nature of the edit. If the edit improves the question so that it's worth someone taking a new look at it, then it makes sense to bump it to the front page. It it's just me removing "thanks in advanced", then I agree it should not be on the front page. I'd be ok with a checkbox that, say, 3k+ users could check to say "keep off the front page".

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of this happening? As far I'm aware the frontpage or / is a random mixture of questions, so it's highly unlikely with everything that's going on you get more than X posts which were edited by an user (unless you are unlucky enough). In my own I see only 1 modified and 9 asked/answered of the top 10 and neither are by the same user.

Comment: @Braiam Part of the problem is that you don't know when it is happening. You click on a question link, looking for someone to assist, and discover that this thing is old. But it does sometimes occur that you can see it, because you see "modified by" the same person for several questions.

Answer (score 16):

One of the main reasons for edits bumping questions to the home page is to make sure that we get several pairs of eyes on the edit as a way of guarding against vandalism and spam.

If the edit didn't bump the question it could remain on the site for days, weeks or even months before someone spotted the problem and fixed or flagged it.

It's one of the ways we keep the site clean.

Comment: So maybe, as I suggest in my edit, what I should be asking for is more info on the home page about when the question was _originally_ asked. That way, I won't waste time going to old questions if I don't want to.

Comment: @matt, Yes, that would be nice. There was a proposal [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288737/always-show-asker-on-the-front-page), but people were not very enthusiastic about it.

Answer (score 6):

> ... editing very old questions and answers, for no earthly reason that I can see ...

We sometimes go through old questions to clean up (or just burninate) a specific tag. On more then one occasion people would complain about bumping questions when doing this and tbh I really don't see a way around this.

When cleaning up a tag we basically have three things we can do:

1. manually go through the questions
2. request that somebody from the SO (/ mod?) team does a bulk burnination
3. leave the tags

If there aren't too many questions with said crap tag we would normally use do first. Meaning questions will get bumped to the front page. Reason for this is that some questions are useful and don't deserve to be closed and deleted, but rather retagged (while fixing other issues when found).

Option two is something that does not happen often (AFAIK), because simply removing a tag leaves questions without tags and other issues that should be fixed either way.

Option 3 has the same problems as option two only with the bonus of not cleaning up at all.

As you can see in most cases we will go for option one, because it's the easiest (and often the sanest) to do and the fact that questions are bumped are taken for granted.

I for one would love a way to prevent bumping questions when doing cleanups, but IIRC this has been asked before on several occasions and was always declined.

I know you said you don't really care about why people edit old / ancient questions, but I felt the need to explain (at least one reason) either way.